# How to calculate the derivative of $F=\frac{e^{W}-1}{W}$ where $W = [\omega]_\times$ in $\omega$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, lie-derivative

How to calculate the derivative of $F=\frac{e^{W}-1}{W}$ in $\omega$ where $W = [\omega]_\times$ and $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^3$?

I am aware of a solution (**solution 1**) and briefly show below, but I am not happy with it for its complexity and am looking for a possibly better solution (**solution 2**). Inspired by [hans'](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/309196/hans) brilliant answer to a related question of mine, [how to derive the inverse of F](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085873/how-to-derive-the-inverse-of-f-i-alpha-thetaw-beta-thetaw2-where-w), I am now working on solving it by applying the Sylvester interpolation. The problem lies in that the result derived in solution 2 doesn't agree with 1 which has been verified using c++. It will be greatly appreciated if you could take a look. Thanks in advance!

### solution 1:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega_i}=& \frac{\partial \frac{e^{[\omega]_\times}-I}{[\omega]_\times}}{\partial \omega_i}=\frac{\partial (\mathbf{I}+\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2}[\omega]_\times+\frac{\theta-\sin\theta}{\theta^3}[\omega]^2_\times)}{\partial \omega_i}\\
=&\frac{\partial(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2})}{\partial \omega_i}[\omega]_\times+ \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2}\frac{\partial [\omega]_\times}{\partial \omega_i} + \frac{\partial(\frac{\theta-\sin\theta}{\theta^3})}{\partial \omega_i}[\omega]^2_\times+ \frac{\theta-\sin\theta}{\theta^3}\frac{\partial [\omega]^2_\times}{\partial \omega_i}\\
=&(\frac{-2(1-\cos\theta)}{\theta^3}+\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta^2})\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \omega_i}[\omega]_\times+(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2})[e_i]_\times+(\frac{-3(\theta-\sin\theta)}{\theta^4}+\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^3})\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \omega_i}[\omega]^2_\times\\
&+\frac{\theta-\sin\theta}{\theta^3}(\mathbf{e}_i\mathbf{v}^\top+\mathbf{v}^\top\mathbf{e}_i-2\omega_i\mathbf{I})\\
=&(\frac{-2(1-\cos\theta)}{\theta^3}+\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta^2})\frac{\omega_i}{\theta}[\omega]_\times+(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2})[e_i]_\times+(\frac{-3(\theta-\sin\theta)}{\theta^4}+\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^3})\frac{\omega_i}{\theta}[\omega]^2_\times\\&+\frac{\theta-\sin\theta}{\theta^3}(\mathbf{e}_i\mathbf{v}^\top+\mathbf{v}^\top\mathbf{e}_i-2\omega_i\mathbf{I})\\
=&\frac{-2\theta+3\sin\theta-\theta\cos\theta}{\theta^4}\frac{\omega_i}{\theta}W^2+\frac{-2+2\cos\theta+\theta\sin\theta}{\theta^3}\frac{\omega_i}{\theta}W\\
&+(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2})[e_i]_\times+\frac{\theta-\sin\theta}{\theta^3}(\mathbf{e}_i\mathbf{v}^\top+\mathbf{v}^\top\mathbf{e}_i-2\omega_i\mathbf{I})
\end{align*}
where $I$ is an identity matrix, $e_i$ is the $i$-th column of $I$ and $\theta=||\omega||$

### solution 2:

we want to calculate
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega_i}=\frac{\partial \frac{e^{[\omega]_\times}-I}{[\omega]_\times}}{\partial \omega_i}$, so I am thinking of solving $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \omega_i}$, where $f(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ so we have:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \omega_i}=&\frac{\partial \frac{e^z-1}{z}}{\partial \omega_i}\\
=& \frac{\partial \frac{1}{z}}{\partial \omega_i}(e^z-1) +\frac{1}{z}\frac{\partial (e^z-1)}{\partial \omega_i}\\
=& -\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \omega_i}(e^z-1) +\frac{1}{z}e^z\frac{\partial z}{\partial \omega_i}\\
=&\frac{1-e^z}{z^2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \omega_i}+\frac{e^z}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \omega_i}\\
=&\frac{1-e^z+ze^z}{z^2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \omega_i}
\end{align*}
Because of Sylvester interpolation, we know that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega_i}=a_2W^2+a_1W+a_0I$ and

\begin{align*}
a_0=&\phi(0)\\
a_1=&\frac{\phi(i\theta)-\phi(-i\theta)}{i2\theta}\\
a_2=&\frac{2\phi(0)-\phi(i\theta)-\phi(-i\theta)}{2\theta^2}
\end{align*}
where $\phi(z)=\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \omega_i}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
a_0=&\frac{1}{2}\\
a_1=&\frac{\sin\theta-\theta\cos\theta}{\theta^3}\\
a_2=&\frac{1}{4\theta^2}+\frac{1-\cos\theta-\theta\sin\theta}{\theta^4}
\end{align*}
However, they do not agree with **solution 1**.
I also tried to derive in the following methods:

Replace $z$ with $W=[\omega]_\times$ then we have:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega_i} =& -\frac{1}{W^2}\frac{\partial W}{\partial \omega_i}(e^W-I) +\frac{1}{W}e^W\frac{\partial W}{\partial \omega_i}\\
=&-\frac{1}{W^2}[e_i]_\times(I+\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}W+\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2}W^2-I) +\frac{1}{W}(I+\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}W+\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2}W^2)[e_i]_\times\\
=&-\frac{1}{W^2}[e_i]_\times\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}W-\frac{1}{W^2}[e_i]_\times\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2}W^2+\frac{1}{W}[e_i]_\times+\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}[e_i]_\times+\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2}W[e_i]_\times
\end{align*}

but I can't reach the results of solution 1 either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution #2 is completely misguided.  Plugging a matrix argument into a scalar derivative is not the same as differentiating that function with respect to a matrix argument.

Consider a simple function to illustrate the point 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= x^3 \cr
 df &= 3x^2\,dx \cr
\cr
}$$
And now the matrix version
$$\eqalign{
 F &= X^3 \cr
 dF &= dX\,X^2 + X\,dX\,X + X^2\,dX \cr
    &\neq 3X^2\,dX\cr
\cr
}$$
In the above, assume that $dz$ stands for the time derivative of $z$.